# What Scheme special forms must the hygienic macro expander know about?

Tags: scheme, syntax-rules

`syntax-rules` in Scheme are "hygienic" and "referentially transparent" and must preserve Scheme's lexical scoping. From my understanding, this means that during the macro expansion phase, the expander would need to know about `lambda` and `define`.

- The expander needs to know about `lambda`.
  Suppose we have this code:

  ```lisp
  (define x 1)
  ((lambda (x) x) 2)
  ```

  If the expander did not know about the `lambda` special form, it would consider the two `x`s in `(lambda (x) x)` to be bound to the `x` in `(define x 1)`, which is incorrect.
- The expander  needs to know about `define`, so that it knows where (i.e. in which scope) a particular identifier is defined. In addition, suppose we have this code:

  ```lisp
  (define n 1)
  (define f (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))
  (define lambda f)
  (lambda n n)
  ```

  In order to correctly determine that both `n` in `(lambda n n)` refer to `(define n 1)`, the expander has to understand that `(define lambda f)` has changed the meaning of `lambda` (and therefore the expander has to stop using special rules for handling `lmabda` in this scope).

What other special forms does the macro expander need to know about? Does it need to know about `set!`?

Answer (score -1):

The examples seem to be about lexical scoping, not macro expansion.

```
(define x 1)
((lambda (x) x) 2)
```

The binding of x in the second line shadows that in the first.

Similarly in the second example `(define lambda f)` binds `lambda`
in the region following the define; there is no macro expansion.

The identifier `lambda` *can* be used as a keyword in a *syntactic extension* (macro);
lexical scoping applies normally, there are no special rules:

```
> (let-syntax ([lambda (syntax-rules ()
        [(lambda arg) ((lambda (x) (+ 1 x)) arg)])])
    (lambda 2))
3
>
```

But:

```
> (letrec-syntax ([lambda (syntax-rules ()
        [(lambda arg) ((lambda (x) (+ 1 x)) arg)])])
    (lambda 2))
Exception: invalid syntax (lambda (x) (+ 1 x))
>
```